# Copying a SQL Server database to local machine

Tags: sql-server

I am using a Parallel Windows to run SSMS. I need to copy a database to my local machine. Can someone suggest some quick way of doing it?

Comment: Make a backup and then restore it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a local backup of MSSQL then copy the backup file to your local machine and then restore it. You need to make sure that it ok first. IF you aren't a DBA they may raise hell if they don't know about it.